# Two nodes stay linked after deleting wires

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have created a node in node-red. When I delete the wire connecting to to another nodes the wire disappears I then deploy the entire flow and although the wire is deleted the node continues to affect the node it was previously joined to. There are nothing else connected to the two node. The issue disappears on restarting node-red.

Are there any flags that I need to disable. It's never happened on any other node and the problem persists across node-red installations.

I'm not sure what code would be causing this issue could you advise me why this would occur? Or what section of the code to post as the files are quite large.

Thank you.

Comment: Which node is causing the problem?

Comment: @hardillb node-red-contrib-homekit-bridged I'm trying to fix it but I've never seen behaviour like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reason why messages should continue to flow if there is no wire between them from a Node-RED point of view, there are no flag/settings that would change this behaviour.

If a specific node shares state between instances (e.g. shared config nodes) then they may still pass some information, but that should be limited to just that node. Without spending time digging through the homekit node I can't say how this behaves.

You may do better discussing this on the Node-RED Slack or Discourse forum as working through it may take some back and forth which is not what Stack Overflow is good for.